# Why is VS 2005 SP1 not recommended for ReSharper 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-xp, resharper, resharper-6.0

I have already asked this question in the JetBrains forums, but I find that questions are usually answered quicker here than there, so here goes -

The system requirements for ReSharper 6.0 state that it will work on VS 2005 SP1, but it is not recommended. Why is that?

I am using it on VS 2005, and am encountering times (particulary in the option modal) when I try to do something (various things) and it crashes my entire work machine (XP Pro SP3) - not just VS 2005.

Comment: Neither Visual Studio nor ReSharper are capable of crashing your machine, as they are user-mode programs. That said, an employer once ran VPN software that included "endpoint security", which used kernel-mode code to watch for every DLL that gets opened. Apparently, the modular nature of VS confused it, and it crashed the system. I was able to reproduce with a simple program that loaded DLLs in a loop until the system crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why VS2005 is not recommended is because we haven't executed pre-release QA procedures with this version of VS as fully as with VS2008 and VS2010, which, in turn, was due to the decreasing VS2005 user base.

As to why your machine is crashing, this could be investigated further through JetBrains support but in our experience, problems like this, especially with Windows XP SP3, are related to obsolete video card drivers. We've had a few similar support cases that were resolved by updating video card drivers.

Comment: Well since the actual question was why vs 2005 sp1 is not supported, and you answered it, i guess i have to accept this answer.  In regards to why my machine is restarting, I have it as another question, so that can be solved there.